# jQuery Script Adding Class to Every Radio Button and Checkbox Label

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does this script add a class to every radio button and checkbox Label on the page, instead of just the ones for each individual checkbox/radio button?

For example, I have these buttons:

```
<input class="required" id="Example31" name="Example3" type="checkbox" />
<label for="Example31">Example Input 3 Option 1</label>

<input class="required" id="Example32" name="Example3" type="checkbox" />
<label for="Example32">Example Input 3 Option 2</label>

<input class="required" id="Example4" name="Example4" type="radio" />
<label for="Example4">Example Input 4</label>
```

And this script:

```
$("input.required").each(function() {
    if ($(this + ":checkbox") || $(this + ":radio")) {
        if (!$(this + ":checked").val()) {
            var inputId = $(this).attr("id");
            $("label[for=" + inputId + "]").addClass("error");
        };
    };
});
```

The script fires when I click a button. If no box is checked, every label gets an error added to it, which is correct. However, if one box is checked, no label gets an error on it, which is incorrect. If I check a checkbox in the first group, but leave the radio button unchecked, that radio button should be marked as an error.

NOTE: I know this script doesn't account form the input names just yet (so if one checkbox with the same name is checked, the other would currently display an error), I'm trying to get his bug worked out before moving forward.

Comment: You are trying to concatenate a DOM element (I assume `this` refers to one) with a string... that can only go wrong.

Comment: To add to what @FelixKling said, what element is `this` referring to?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. @RoryMcCrossan I only posted a snipet of the code, I'll update it.

Comment: What do you expect the result of `this + ":checkbox"` to be?

Comment: I updated the code, `this` refers to `$("input.required")`

Comment: I'm surprised that Sizzle doesn't not throw an error for the selector, because it is far from what you want, but here is an explanation for why it adds the class to every `input`: `$(this + ":checkbox")` returns a jQuery object, it is always truish. `$(this + ":checked").val()` is always `undefined` because jQuery cannot find such an element (`this + ":checkbox"`). Hence the condition is always `true`. So, both `if`s are true for all of the selected elements.

Comment: FYI, `this` does not refer to `$("input.required")`, it refers to a DOM element inside the jQuery object (so to speak, one of the selected elements). Then you are trying to perform *string* concatenation of a *DOM element* with a string, only that the string representation of a DOM element is not suitable as selector. For example, the string representation of an `input` element is `"[object HTMLInputElement]"`. So your selector ends up being `"[object HTMLInputElement]:checkbox"`, which is certainly not what you intend to do :)

Comment: I'm very curious about why `[object DomElement]:checkbox` is a valid jQuery selector. `[object]:checkbox` is a valid selector and works as expected, but `[object DomElement]` raises an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines of code are complete nonsense, they cannot do anything useful or sane:

```
if ($(this + ":checkbox") || $(this + ":radio")) {
    if (!$(this + ":checked").val()) {
```

I suspect you're trying to do...

```
if ($(this).is(":checkbox") || $(this).is(":radio")) {
    if (!$(this).is(":checked")) {
```

By way of explanation,

1. `this + ":checkbox"` will *always* produce a selector like `[object Something]:checkbox`, where `Something` will vary based on the value of `this`
2. This will match `:checkbox` elements <strike>which have the attributes `object` and `Something`, (see [Has Attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/))</strike> which is almost certainly not what you want and will very likely match no elements; **Actually I'm not sure why this works; `[object]` is a valid selector, and `[object Something]:checkbox` is a working (but likely invalid - jQuery bug?) selector but `[object Something]` is an invalid selector and raises an error**
3. Regardless of whether elements were matched `$("...)` will *always* produce a jQuery object with 0 or more elements, which is *always* truthy. Instead of `if ($(...)) {`, you need to check `if ($(...).length > 0)`

To summarize, you're producing an invalid selector which (through some quirk of jQuery) doesn't raise an error, but which returns completely bogus results.

Comment: Thanks. I just learned about that `:checkbox` and `:radio` thing today, so I must've been a bit confused about how to use the syntax. I'll accept in 5 minutes when it'll let me.